# How to write a function to disconnect client from server in C?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, shutdown

I tried server client tcp code in c, I want to add some functionality to disconnect client from server. I search on google for it. I found function `shutdown()`, I am not getting idea how to do it ?

Comment: by closing the client socket ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disconnect a client from the server, just `close` the fd linked to this client.
To disconnect a client to a server from the client, just `close` the client socket.

This is a quick way to disconnect, but don't forget to send a last exit message when you are leaving from a server / disconnecting a client.

No need of shutdown here. (Except if you share fd between processes, but without more information we cannot be more precise)